# Showing Selected Data

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a list of items that are looping through a JSON file displaying specific data. When one of the list items are selected I want the user to be taken to another page and displayed further information about the selected item.

This is the code I have below, I am also very new to JS and React-Native.

```
          {
      data.stores.map(store => (
        <Card button onPress={() => this.props.navigation}>
          <CardItem header>
            <Text>{store.storeId} - {store.storeName}</Text>
            <Right>
              <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
            </Right>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      ))
      }
```

My JSON file could look like this:

```
 stores: [
{
storeId: 2,
storeName: "Blah",
phone: "0404040404",
Status: "Retail Partner",
Manager: "Blah",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you use **react-navigation** for navigation. You can follow the example

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

Here is the solution

```
{
  data.stores.map(store => (
    <Card button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate( "routeName",{data : store })}>
      <CardItem header>
        <Text>{store.storeId} - {store.storeName}</Text>
        <Right>
          <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
        </Right>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>
  ))
  }
```

In the next page, you will found it in

```
this.props.navigation.state.params
```